# why can't i return array values to main function?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I am created a main function for thread creation in Linux with a function to read that data . my main code contain initialization of thread as :

main function :

```
int main(int argc , /*no of aruments*/
            char *argv[])/*store each argument values*/
 {
    pthread_t thid[count];
    create_thread(argv,count,&thid);

 }
```

and my function as :

```
int create_thread(char *argv[],int count , pthread_t **thid)
{
     for(index = 1; index <= count; index++)
    {

         status = pthread_create(&thid[index],NULL,file_op,(void*)   mystruct);/*create main threads*/
    }
}
```

I got error like

```
function.c:: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type
 /usr/include/pthread.h: note: expected ‘pthread_t * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘pthread_t **
```

and

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘create_thread’ from    incompatible pointer type
function.c:: note: expected ‘pthread_t **’ but argument is of type ‘pthread_t (*)[(long unsigned int)(count)]’
```

is there any problem problem on thread code ? how I declare correct syntax ? I want to get all values from function to main array .

Comment: For debugging, how about starting with just one thread, and not trying to have an array of pthred_t's.   That array is complicating the type declarations, and making it hard to see what the error might be.

Comment: I have declared the array pthread_t thid[count]; in my main function and I am passing using double pointer to the create function . why can't I do it like this way ??

Comment: If you are going to pass it that way, then you are going to have to dereference properly as well.  You shouldn't pass something as a pointer that you don't intend on changing.  You don't intend on changing the thid, you only want to change the contents of the array, so pass a pointer to the array (thid) and not a pointer to the pointer to an array (&thid).

Comment: Currently, your MCVE doesn't compile and as a result I can't reproduce your error messages/warnings using this code. I get something completely different. If you don't wish for this to be closed, please read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make two changes:

```
create_thread(argv,count,thid);
```

and

```
int create_thread(char *argv[],int count , pthread_t *thid)
```

That will pass the array to your function and it will pass a pointer to one of the thread IDs to be updated by pthread_create.

Answer (score 4):

**pthread_create** function's first parameter requires `pthread_t *` . You are passing wrong type of argument.

Check this out: [pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)

Answer (score 2):

Also `create_thread()` is writing beyond the end of the `thid` array. The loop should be

```
for (index = 0; index < count; index++)
```